# separate preventDefault() from function

Tags: jquery

Instead of something like this

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //to avoid the submit button to reload the page and go page to page one.
/* computing dimensions */
});
```

I'd like to put my function somewhere else,  like this :

```
$('#submitbutton').click(computeUserDimensions);

function computeUserDimensions(){
/* computing dimensions */
}
```

But then I don't where to put the `preventDefault` to provide the click (which is on a submit button) to go to another page.

Can you help me figure this out?

Thanks

Comment: put to bottom of the event the preventDefault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the function call to be an anonymous function that handles the click and calls the sub function.

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault(); computeUserDimensions();});

function computeUserDimensions(){
/* computing dimensions */
}
```

Comment: what if I need to pass a variable (array) to computeUserDimensions in :`$('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault(); computeUserDimensions();});
`? Should I write : `$('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault(); computeUserDimensions(prodata);});
`

Comment: @user130482 yes (provided `prodata` is correctly populated array).

Answer (score 5):

Add parameter `event` to your function and it will be passed by `jQuery` implicitly.

```
$('#submitbutton').click(computeUserDimensions);

function computeUserDimensions(event){
    /* computing dimensions */
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works (but with `event̀ instead of `e`). Thanks!

Comment: What is the difference between writing 
`$('#submitbutton').click(computeUserDimensions);


 function computeUserDimensions(event){
 ...}`
and 
`$('#submitbutton').click(function() {
 computeUserDimensions();
});


function computeUserDimensions(event){
...}`

Comment: In first you are passing reference of defined function and in second you are passing function (anonymous).

Comment: ok. Problem in this solution is if I want to reuse the function with another event, and don't want to preventDefault on this other function. The solution from Kami seems to handle this.

Comment: That method is already using two functions one anonymous and other named so you can make two named functions again and put the common code in one function and call from other.

Answer (score 1):

```
function computeUserDimensions(e){

   var evt = e ? e:window.event;
   if (evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();

   /* computing dimensions */

}
```

Comment: the problem in this solution is if I want to reuse the function with another event, and don't want to preventDefault on this other function. The solution from Kami seems to handle this